# Use dynamic image src as prop Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-props

I am trying to send a dynamic src as prop to imageComponent, but i am doing it wrong. fileName = about.gsx$imagesrc.$t does not work. The images are stored in asset/Pictures and about.gsx$imagesrc.$t is the same value as the image name.

```
<template>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-content" v-for="about in state.aboutData" :key="about.index">
      
        <div class="fill-circle">
          <h2 class="timeline-year" > {{about.gsx$year.$t}}</h2>
        </div>
      <p class="timeline-text" > {{about.gsx$happening.$t}} </p>

        <ImageComponent
          //Filename is the problem
          fileName= about.gsx$imagesrc.$t
          leftPosition="200px"
          activeColor="#132766"
        />
     
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { state } from '@/store/index.js'
import ImageComponent from "@/components/UI-kit/PictureModules/Sko.vue"

export default {
  name:"Timeline",
  components: {ImageComponent},
}
```

The Image component

```
<template>
    <div class="ImageComponent" v-bind:style="{ left: leftPosition}">
        <img class="image" :src="require(`@/assets/Pictures/${fileName}`)">
        <div class="shadow" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: activeColor}"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"ImageComponent",
    props: {
        activeColor: [String],
        leftPosition: [String],
        fileName: [String],
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the error i get

Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './about.gsx$imagesrc.$t'"

Comment: I have also tries this: fileName= "`${about.gsx$imagesrc.$t`}", but still does not work.

Comment: what about `:src="require('@/assets/Pictures/'+fileName+')'">`

Comment: `:fileName="about.gsx$imagesrc.$t"`